# How to prevent folders from roaming with a profile?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

We do not want users' data located in a specific folder that is to be synced back to the server.

We are using Windows server 2003.

Thanks
we have tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814592

Comment: The KB article you posted is correct. What's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

One other place that server likes to enable roaming at is in the user account properties, profile tab. Make sure these fields aren't populated.[image: User Properties]